# Can't upload a picture in SQL Server AdventureWorks DB with php

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to upload a picture in AdventureWorks database with PHP code.
I'm getting an error. I've made a throughout search and can't fix it.

**Error Code**

sqlsrv_execute() failed. Row insertion failed. Error information:

```
SQLSTATE: 07002  
Code: 0  
Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error.
```

**Code:**

```
case 'uploadpicture':
    $tsql = "INSERT INTO FotoFGS (LargePhoto)
             VALUES (?); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS PhotoID";

    $fileStream = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");

    $uploadPic = sqlsrv_prepare(
        $conn,
        $tsql,
        array(&$fileStream,
              SQLSRV_PARAM_IN,
              SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY),
              SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARBINARY('max')
        )
    ));

    sqlsrv_execute($uploadPic);

    if ($uploadPic === false) {
        die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
    }

    if (sqlsrv_execute($uploadPic) === false) {
        echo "sqlsrv_execute() failed.\n";
        echo "Row insertion failed.\n";
        die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
    }
```

Thanks you kindly for your help.

Comment: It looks like you have an extraneous closing parenthesis in your `sqlsrv_prepare` function call.

Comment: @Sarcastron. You were right. I've corrected & indented 
the code & now it's working OK. 
Thank you very much for your kindly help.
now I've got another error : 
SQLSTATE: 2400, 
Code : 0, 
Message: Invalid cursor state. 
May I ask for your help ?

Comment: If you have a different issue you should start a new question. That way you can better identify a specific question and also because the answers will be in a more helpful format for others who may be experiencing a simlar issue.

Comment: @Sarcastron .Thanks for your advice. I've started a new question,
about four hours ago.
Its tittle is "Failed to upload a picture in AdventureWorks database with PHP",
but i don't know how to relate this new question with the
former one.
In fact I don't knew how to edit the former post.
Like you see I'm a newbie (not in programming) but in Stack overflow, and this is
juzst my second question.